# Create a button that starts a 24 hour countdown in a cell and clears the data in that cell when it reaches zero

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know this will be an easy thing for most everyone on this site but I just can't figure it out on my own.  I basically want what the picture here shows.
[image]

I've found several possible solutions but they just don't fit exactly how I want it to work.  I want it to be easy for users to open the spreadsheet and press one button by their name, then a countdown starts in column C, and when it reaches zero the cell clears and it can be done again.

One of the possible solutions I was messing around with was [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ixdqHD378UAq944AI-rH6Cr2kZPy_Vk3MO-O51ujf-k/edit#gid=0), which I found from YouTube.  I made multiple users, one for each person and modifying these functions:

```
function addRecord(b, c) {
   var row = getNextRow();
   setValue('B' + row, b);
   setValue('C' + row, c);
}

function punchIn() {
  addRecord(new Date(), '=(B2+G1-now())');
}
```

While I think this would be fine (although generate a lot of unnecessary rows) I don't know how to get the script to choose other cells besides B2, it needs to select B3, B4, B5, and so on. G1 holds the 24 hour (24:00:00.000) timer.  I've since decided just to abandon that and ask for help and maybe someone can make the simplified version with just a button next to each user name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: In your sample spreadsheet there is an `In` and an `Out` button, but you only mentioned one button per row. There's also a column with `In` and `Out` values. Could you please clarify about that?

Comment: The sample worksheet was one I found and was trying to modify it to work simply by only starting a timer next to each user name.  The only button I'm using is the "In" button which I modified to add the timer instead of entering "in" into the cell

Comment: After poking around here trying to find a solution, I was able to get this working: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfxZDzBn7-UW6Wh9L9bnZegacaDyBg_mBaJJ5XwqL6A/edit?usp=sharing) but now I need it the timer to stop when it reaches zero

Comment: I thought you didn't want to have a different script for each row. Isn't that the case? In your current spreadsheet, you have a button for each row, each of them attached to a different function. Also, the spreadsheet you shared is in your Trash, and the script cannot be accessed. Could you please share the code related to the functions you're currently using? I'd like to help you, but don't know what is your current situation and your desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had found another solution and just scrapped that whole thing, I removed it from the trash if you still desire to take a look.  I didn't necessarily mind having a different script for each row, I just figured there was probably an easier way to go about it.  The solution I found works well enough even though I had to modify it more for use on mobile devices since buttons don't seem to work.  Thanks for replying and trying to help

Comment: For the timer to stop when it reaches zero, you could use `=IF(B2+B1-now()<0,,B2+B1-now()<0)` or, if you want to get rid of the formula entirely, install a time-driven trigger to check periodically whether the timer is above zero, and remove the formula if that's not the case. Also, I thought you could use checkboxes instead of buttons. This could be used in mobile and would allow you to use a single script for all rows. Would this be appropriate for your situation? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer.

Comment: Sorry the formula would be `=IF(B2+B1-now()<0,,B2+B1-now())`